# OpenOffice BASIC IsNumber

Tags: vba, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

I have to migrate document from MS Excel to Open Office with macros. Everything works fine except this function

```
 If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(12, 5)) = False Then
   MsgBox "Nesprávne zadané číslo účtu alebo kód banky!", vbCritical
   ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="****", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
   Exit Sub
 End If
```

It's check for values inserted by user. But I get only this error:

BASIC runtime error
Variable of object is not set

So I double checked my document, if cell E12 is not empty, but it was filled.
Is there in Open Office a different way to check input format?
Thanks

Comment: check out some premade documents you can see the excel use for A1-1,1 and oo 0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number in Excel Visual basic is different like in oo. try use getCellByName("E12").Value  this function returns you Number

Answer (score 0):

If the line `If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(12, 5)) = False Then` fails saying `object not set`, and you've verified that `Cells(12, 5)` returns a a value, then the only possibilities that I can think of would be that either `Application` or `Application.WorksheetFunction` is `Nothing`.